# Bad line of code in .csproj partially disables Intellisense for Unity, permanently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, csproj

I was editing the .csproj file for my Unity project and I accidentally added a `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` line of code on a line where it caused an error in Visual Studio (0x80004005). Since then Intellisense has been unable to suggest Unity-specific classes etc, such as Rigidbody. They don't even get proper color coding anymore but appear white instead.

Fixing the error in the .csproj file does not restore Intellisense's functionality, even if I replace the whole file with a backup created seconds before the error occured. I've tested this with multiple new projects. Reopening Unity/Visual Studio or restarting the computer does not help either.

Reproducing the problem with any project is easy. It happens every time I add a line to the file that isn't allowed, such as `<>` on an empty line of code. The only solution that I've found is switching to another version of Visual Studio. However, if I reproduce the error while using the other version of VS, Intellisense gets disabled for that version as well. I've tried this with 2019 and 2022, and the problem occurs with both.

Comment: `I was editing the .csproj file ...` - **Why?!** You are not supposed to edit these. They are the result of Unity precompiling your normal `c#` files. Simply delete it and DoubleClick a script within the Unity Editor -> it will regenerate the `.csproj` and `.sln` files

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you are not supposed to edit the .csproj file!

Instead, you should open the .sln file or just open your scripts from the unity `Project View` (Assets).

You could also try to go into your preferences/external Tools and look if Visual Studio is selected as your editor.